# Good Conferences for Environment Designers

Tags: community, environmental

I'm a graphic designer working in events, pop-ups, retail and brand activations. My work has encouraged me to seek out conferences and learning opportunities and I'm having difficulty finding conferences that are applicable to environment and event design. I'm looking to learn skills relating to designing temporary structures, retail environments, and branded spaces. Does anyone know of good events or conferences related to this field?

Comment: Europe, US, other regions?

Comment: US for me, although other regions could be useful for other users!

Answer (score 1):

Note that I've not attended any of these but they're ones I've come across and have looked into:

[SEGD is Society of Experiential Graphic Designers](https://segd.org/). It encompasses wayfinding, signage, and environmental design. They host a bunch of events; I believe their largest is [SEGD Conference Experience](https://segd.org/events). For your purpose this is probably the best organization.

[Expo! Expo!](https://www.myexpoexpo.com/expoexpo2019/Public/MainHall.aspx) is a conference about conferences hosted by the International Association of Exhibitions and Events.

[ExhibitorLive](https://www.exhibitoronline.com/live/2020/index.asp) is by [Exhibitor magazine](https://www.exhibitoronline.com/magazine/issues.asp). They have some interesting articles though a lot is behind paywalls. I've considered telling my boss I want a subscription but we really aren't large enough to do fancy booths and usually just have a table with a popup display type of deal. Actually it looks like since the last time I looked they may have gone to a free subscription model, not positive. Says its free to signup now, not sure the exact terms and if thats a trial period.

Answer (score 0):

[Art and Environmental Justice](https://www.eventbrite.com/e/hallie-ford-school-of-graduate-studies-2019-symposium-art-environmental-justice-tickets-64998363856). From the event's page:

> The day’s agenda will place the arts at the center of these conversations, investigating how creative practices contribute to community and global struggles for environmental justice.
>
> A free interdisciplinary symposium to promote dialog on the interplay of environmentalism, social justice, education, design, and the arts. Students, scholars, activists, educators, designers, and artists working on environmental justice issues will explore the politics surrounding systemic biases and the ways that environmental degradation and climate change intersect with race, gender, and class to create disproportionate outcomes on both a local and global scale.

Comment: Always quote the source if you copy the text 1:1, I edited for you.